# Can't activate anaconda environment on CentOS

Tags: centos, tensorflow, anaconda, environment

I'm working on install tensorflow on my CentOS system.

I had success install miniconda in my system and created tensorflow environment.
However, I got error message while I run "*source activate tensorflow*".

I checked on Anaconda page and found out the reason is activate file only support bash and zsh. But my OS centOS is csh (C shell).

And I also try to add "*set path* " for the tensorflow environment on my *~/.cshrc* file. But it looks not working, I still get ImportError while I import tensorflow.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following (on CentOS 6.8 or CentOS 7):

```
[root@9dc1f60d1dcd ~]# csh
[root@9dc1f60d1dcd ~]# echo $0
csh
[root@9dc1f60d1dcd ~]# bash Miniconda2-4.3.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /m2
[root@9dc1f60d1dcd ~]# /m2/bin/conda install -y tensorflow
[root@9dc1f60d1dcd ~]# /m2/bin/python
Python 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'0.10.0rc0'
```